# Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native version `0.49.3` and I have created a file index.js in my project directory. it works for ios but when I run it for Android, it gives error

> Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots

Do I need to add something to my android folder?

Answer (score 0):

The default `React Native's` starter included two separated files call `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js`.

If you want to combine root files -

- Create one files (`index.base.js`, `index.app.js`, `index.root.js`, base, etc)
- Register your component using `AppRegistry.registerComponent` in your created files.
- Import created file in each separated files.

#### Example

```js
/**
 * root.js
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'

class AppName extends Component {
  ...
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => AppName )
```

```js
/**
 * index.android.js and index.ios.js
 */

import './root'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Why we are doing it, if we are using react-native version more than 0.44.0 then i think we dont need to create index.android.js and index.ios.js.
i didn't create any index.ios.js but it works in ios.

Comment: only file need to create. We don't need re-create `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` that is included by defualts.

Comment: It's resolved. Have added below line in android/app/build.gradle project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]